# What's wrong with my VoIP setup on Edgerouter X (Telekom Germany)

Tags: sip, router, voip

I'm from germany and my provider is Deutsche Telekom. I'm using ubiquiti edgerouter x with an pppoe connection to Telekom. Internet works well but I can't get VoIP working. My Phone is a Siemens Gigaset C430A GO. Only configuration I did there is following the wizard, entering my phone number and selecting predefined Telekom settings. Those settings should be correct according to Telekom support.

On the edgerouter I've whitelisted and forwarded almost every port to my phone (10.1.0.4).

Please have a look on the tcpdump I took while doing a call from my mobile to my configured landline: https://justpaste.it/4i8n9

The issue is that it is ringing, I pick up, but can't hear anything. After 10 seconds the connection gets closed. In the opposite direction I also can't hear anything but the connection stays open. But: When I hang up on one side, the other side get's notified.

I find this very weird. It does not really look like a problem of a closed port or something else with the firewall. Unfortunately I have no experience with SIP so far so from the log I can't really tell if everything is correct there.

I've change the phone numbers in the log.
111122223333 is the landline I was calling.
444455556666 is my mobile number I was calling from.
777788889999 is also in the log which is another configured landline. I have no idea why this is in the log.
100.200.100.200 is my external IP.
10.1.0.4 is my internal IP for the phone.

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your router's NAT or ALG settings as well as the STUN settings of the phone.

Here is the rationale behind it: the capture you posted shows the remote party expecting media on port 33880 whereas your phone expects it on port 5012. The issue is that while your phone successfully sends out its audio, it is not receiving any in return. Moreover, about a second into the call, your phone is sending a reinvite, this time using its local IP address rather than a publicly routable address:

```
...
o=- 5012 14 IN IP4 10.1.0.4
s=Mapping
c=IN IP4 10.1.0.4
...
```

The reinvite is rejected by the other party on the account of the SDP being bogus (rightfully so), and during the course of the capture, this series of events repeats several times.

- If your router supports ALG and it is enabled, you should attempt reversing this setting as it effectively tampers with the SIP flow through your router; its purpose has been obsoleted by NAT and these days it does more damage than help;
- If your router's NAT settings mandate symmetric NAT, disable it; it's behaviour is consistent with the issue you described (though there can be other reasons for it);
- Check your phone's STUN setting (page 106 of the user manual) and enable it; STUN works great behind NAT when it comes down to traversing your local network by informing the remote party on sending its audio to an working port.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for the information. I figured out that the edgerouter indeed has an SIP ALG. I've deactivated that one. Then I've changed the standard SIP and RTP ports to something custom just to make sure nothing is trying to do some SIP magic still. It still didn't work until I tried disabling STUN. Now it works. But why not. I'm forwarding now only the ports that are really needed and my phone don't need to do STUN for no reason. Firewall rules allow packages from the Telekom SIP range to my phone. Everything is fine now.